# Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 issues in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, intel-wireless

I have a laptop with with the Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 and am running Ubuntu 18.04 (although the problem existed with 17.10 and I presume this is a general problem).  At home the Wifi works well, however, on some networks it will intermittently disconnect.  Using Gnome network manager and turning the Wi-fi off and back on could fix the issue, but not always.  This could happen numerous times a day.

Comment: Thanks psiphi75, your fix is good. Works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. vi /etc/default/crda. Set to proper REGDOMAIN vi /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
Add this options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much research and reading the [Kernel documentation](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) on this, I found that making all the following changes work.

Change the wi-fi country code ([thanks to this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2331242)). As root edit `/etc/default/crda` and set the following to your country code:

```
REGDOMAIN={ISO COUNTRY CODE}
```

Disable Bluetooth, although this is a dual-band adapter, it's not good at handling Bluetooth and wi-fi at the same time. From the [Kernel documentation](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi):

> For users of these devices who have problems when Wi-Fi and Bluetooth
>   are running concurrently, we suggest to disable BT Coex by loading
>   iwlwifi with bt_coex_active=0 as a module parameter.

Also from the Kernel documentation also [discusses](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#about_platform_noise) that the device does not handle 2.4 Ghz noise very well and recommends the following:

> ```
> - Disable Wi-Fi's power save (prevent the PCIe link to go to power save): power_save=0 module parameter for iwlmvm
> - Disable USB3 in BIOS (if possible), it not, just stop using it
> - Disable 40MHz on 2.4GHz: cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz module parameter
> - Use 5GHz band (on devices that support 5GHz operation)
> ```

In a nutshell, I did not disable USB3 in BIOS. But did the others, to implement these changes add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @chili555, the Kernel driver page appears to be out-dated/incorrect, the `power_scheme` value does not exists and appears that we should use `power_save=0`.  Documentation updated.

A good resource for debugging the iwlwifi driver is https://support.system76.com/articles/wireless/

Comment: Please check: `modinfo iwlwifi`. I think you mean power_level or power_save. power_scheme is not an available parameter. If you mean for this parameter to apply to iwlmvm, then it needs its own conf file:`options iwlmvm power_scheme=1`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue temporarily by running this code (The selected Country should support Dual-band 5Ghz US/DE/...):

```
 # iw reg set US
```

or add this as a permanent solution:

```
echo "COUNTRY=US" > /etc/sysconfig/regdomain
```

And these code as check:

```
 # iw reg get
 # iw list
```