# Thinkpad T440s Intel 7260 wifi card issues on Ubuntu (but no problems on Windows)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on my t440s (dual-boot setup with windows 10) and the wifi keeps disconnecting. I did some research and apparently this is a common problem with my card (7260).

However, on Windows 10, I rarely ever get this issue while on Ubuntu the wifi is gone within 5-10 minutes after booting and I have to reboot to get it working again.

Here is what I already tried:

- disabling bluetooth in BIOS
- disabling USB 3.0
- applying the fixes mentioned in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034229/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-7260-issues-in-ubuntu-18-04)

fwupdate -l output:

```
failed: no volumes of type c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b: no volumes of type ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @matigo I edited my question with the output but I don't think this was expected.

Comment: The `no volumes of type` issue is unexpected. I've seen that on Fedora, but not Ubuntu. A different matter for a different day, perhaps. Do you have hardware enablement configured?

Comment: I haven't heard of hardware enablement. Is there a way to check if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I own a Thinkpad T440p and it has an Intel 7260. Here are my suggestions.

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Your wireless may be dropping because the channel to which it was connected has suddenly changed.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?